# Whta does alt+/ do in zsh?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, zsh

Using `zsh`, suddenly found that pressing `alt+/` shows a message:

> zsh: do you wish to see all 18221 possibilities (18448 lines)?

After pressing <kbd>y</kbd>, it starts listing a long list of item. What is that list?

<sub>**NOTE:** 
(after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>/</kbd> fast, otherwise is shows the last argument of the last command)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually reproduce this on zsh, I'm guessing you have some option enabled which I don't, but what you describe sounds like the default behavior for bash as well, where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> attempts to complete whatever you have written.

It's basically like <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> with nothing written at the prompt, it will try to complete from the full list of possible completions, which is why you see that message. This is documented in `man bash`, in the "Completing" subsection of the "Readline" section:

> complete-filename (M-/)
>                   Attempt filename completion on the text before point.

I also found this in `man zhscompsys`:

> _history_complete_word (\e/)
>                      Complete words from the shell's command history. This uses the list, remove-all-dups, sort, and stop styles.

The `\e` *should* be ESC (escape), but perhaps you've remapped something?

So, it should be one of "complete-filename" or "_history_complete_word", if you test it a bit, you should be able to figure out which.

Comment: Thanks, but did you press `Alt + /` as fast as possible? In `bash`, yes it acts like `Tab` but in `zsh`, it shows lots of lines {As I said 18448 lines, each line containing one `word` (mostly commands) or `filename`}

Comment: @MohammadKholghi well, that sounds exactly like an attempt to complete. Is it alphabetical? The zsh function in my answer should return sorted results.

Comment: But complete what? Do you press them when nothing is typed and terminal is empty? (And no, that's not alphabetical.)

Comment: @MohammadKholghi commands and file names, I guess :) But I'm just guessing. And yes, I did it immediately in zsh (hold Alt down, and while holding it down, press `/`) and it did nothing. My zsh is unchanged from the defaults, so I really think it's something you have. Try making a new user, logging in as that user and running zsh. Do you see the same behavior? Also, if nobody answers you after a day or so, I suggest you delete this question and ask on [unix.se] instead. We have a lot of zsh experts there, but not so many here.

Comment: I think you're right. After commenting `oh-my-zsh`, it stopped working. Idk what `oh-my-zsh` does with 'Alt + /' @terdon